# Getting 100x100 profile pic using Facebook API, Firebase and Swift

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase, swift3

My project had been getting the URL string for the medium sized profile pic using this code:

```
 let downloadMediumPicTask = session.dataTask(with:       mediumProfPictureURL) { (data, response, error)
        in
        // The download has finished.
        if let e2 = error {
            print("Error downloading profile picture: \(e2)")
        } else {
            if let res2 = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Downloaded medium profile picture with response code \(res2.statusCode)")
                if let imageData2 = data {
                    mediumProfilePictureUIImageFile = UIImage(data: imageData2)!
                    print("mediumProfilePictureUIImageFile has now been defined as: \(mediumProfilePictureUIImageFile).")
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                }
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
            }
        }
    }
    downloadMediumPicTask.resume()
```

It crashes here giving a 403 response code. The URL that is being referenced is an expired signature URL from Facebook. Firebase doesn't adjust to get the new appropriate URL, and it was from Firebase that I had been getting the URL. I can't figure out how to get it directly as tried below:

```
   func getUrlOfMediumProfilePic(){

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        let graphPathPart2 = "me/picture"
        let paramsPart2 = ["type":"medium", "redirect":"false"]
        let completionHandlerPart2 = { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result: Any?, error: Error?) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Medium picture graph call contained an error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else {
                guard connection != nil else {
                    print("getURLOfLargeProfilePic() function aborted bc connection failed.")
                    return
                }
                let results = result! as! NSDictionary
                let dataDict = results["data"] as! NSDictionary
                stringOfMediumProfilePicURLaka100x100 = dataDict["url"] as! String
                print("medium picture graph call results define stringOfMediumProfilePicURLaka100x100 as: \(stringOfMediumProfilePicURLaka100x100)")
            }
        }
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: graphPathPart2, parameters: paramsPart2)!
        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: completionHandlerPart2)
    }else{
        print("User not logged in when getURLOfMediumProfilePic() function was run.")
        return
    }
}
```

This code yields an error with code 8.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?width=100&height=100
```

I don't know swift, so I can't help about syntax. I think you can make http request to url and get image.
Hope this help :)